# Including my slider won't show up [Wordpress]

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

Whenever I try to include my slider script into my header container it doesn't show up. When I use the script as a standalone script it works perfectly fine.

At freshmusicplaylist .com/wp-content/slider/slider.php you can see the working slider.

I want to include it at freshmusicplaylist .com

The script for the slider:
pastebin .com/NGURdE2H (please note it has been minified).

Am I overseeing something? I tried to load the javascript / ajax into a special loader, without success.

Comment: In order to determine the problem, you need to include the code where you are trying to add your slider (i.e. your php where the slider is being added).

Comment: Hi,
You are including the custom php file into your wordpress header. 
Which is working fine. But the way you are loading jquery library and plugin, its not working.

1) Donot load jQuery twice on your page. Your wordpress theme may have already loaded jQuery so if you load jQuery again in your custom php file, it will create conflict.

2) use `jQuery` instead of `$`

3) You are using cloudflare rocket loader which is giving lots of error. 

4) So many errors , get professional help.

Comment: I will check into both of these. Maybe I can solve some of these errors myself. I have also tried to load the code without the jquery api script, but without succes. I have included the script in the pastebin in the original post, however it is minified. I will try to put a complete code later today. Thanks for the information so far.